# Problema na comparação de campo com data e hora

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma consulta onde observei que um dos campos usados na comparação traz data e hora, sendo comparado com a data atual do dia sem hora, isso pode causar problemas no retorno dos dados:?

ex:

```html
      select  top(5)
   p.codinterno, 
   c.dtHrProcesso --pega um horário fixo 
   FROM  TABELA p
   INNER JOIN  TABELAC c on c.idProcesso = p.idProcesso
   WHERE CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) = '2016-11-23' -- comando CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comprando : 2016-11-23 05:35:33.690 = '2016-11-23'
O melhor seria utilizar :

```html
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATETIME), 120) = '2016-11-23'
```

Ou não tem influência no resultado?

Comment: qual é o tipo do campo dtHrProcesso?

Comment: e do tipo DATETIME, gravando data e hora junto

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sim, causa problema no retorno de dados. No seu exemplo, os dados compreendidos entre '23/11/2016 00:01' e '23/11/2016 23:59' não serão retornados na consulta.

Enfrento esse problema no meu ambiente de trabalho e costumo solucioná-lo de duas formas diferentes:

Exemplo: Buscar todos os registros do dia 23/11/2016.

**1 - Primeira forma**

```
SELECT * FROM MOVIMENTOS
WHERE movData BETWEEN '23/11/2016' AND '23/11/2016 23:59:59'
```

**2 - Segunda forma**

```
SELECT * FROM MOVIMENTOS
WHERE movData >= '23/11/2016' AND movData < '24/11/2016'
```

ou

```
SELECT * FROM MOVIMENTOS
WHERE movData >= '23/11/2016' AND movData < DATEADD('d', 1, '23/11/2016')
```

Se o campo é do tipo DATA e possui hora, é imperativo colocar a hora no filtro da consulta também, sob penas do conjunto de dados retornado estar incorreto.

Comment: Como no código de itasouza o valor da coluna dtHrProcesso (do tipo datetime) é convertido previamente para date, antes da comparação, então o código de itasouza não causa nenhum erro no retorno dos dados.

Comment: O problema do retorno de dados é **não** retornar os dados corretamente. Dizer que '23/12/2016 03:57:09' é igual a '23/12/2016' é errado. Quando você compara '23/12/2016' está na verdade comparando '23/12/2016 00:00'. Além do custo representado pelo CAST para cada linha.

Comment: Se movdata for '23/11/2016 23:59:10', o que ocorre no código "primeira forma" por você proposto?

Comment: A não contabilização dos segundos só não foi colocada porque não achei relevante para exemplificar a questão. Mas é implícita e depende da granularidade do dados armazenado e da necessidade. No meu caso não armazeno, por isso não constou nos meus exemplos. De qualquer forma vou editar e colocar. Esse é o motivo da negativa?

Comment: Tou vendo 2 problemas mais sérios na resposta. O primeiro é que você está ignorando o cast pra date que o autor fez, que invalida suas considerações sobre a hora, que passa a ser irrelevante. O segundo é que você faz uma comparação com 23:59:59, ou seja, continua o prolema, se for 23:59:59.378. Quanto à segunda forma, ela até faz sentido como resposta complementar (para quem não quer ou não pode usar o cast) mas aí você explicar melhor as vantagens e desvantagens. Infelizmente a segunda forma por si só não é suficiente pra salvar a resposta, se deixar os outros equivocos mencionados.

Answer (score 2):

@itasouza, a forma que você utiliza é confiável, pois converteu previamente de *datetime* para *date*. Ou seja, a comparação será sempre entre dois operandos do tipo *date*. Não causa nenhum problema no retorno dos dados.

```
-- código original do itasouza
select  top(5)
   p.codinterno, 
   c.dtHrProcesso --pega um horário fixo 
   FROM  TABELA p
   INNER JOIN  TABELAC c on c.idProcesso = p.idProcesso
   WHERE CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) = '2016-11-23'
```

Observe que, se em determinada linha o valor da coluna c.dtHrProcesso for 
"2016-11-23 05:35:33.690", teremos então a seguinte comparação:

```
 Cast('2016-11-23 05:35:33.690' as date) = '2016-11-23'
```

que é o mesmo que

```
 '2016-11-23' = '2016-11-23'
```

---

Para quem está em dúvida se o código original proposto por @itasouza está correto, basta executar o código a seguir.

```
-- código #1
declare @TABELAC table (Seq int identity, dtHrProcesso datetime);

INSERT into @TABELAC (dtHrProcesso) values
  (convert(datetime, '2016-11-23 03:55:18', 120)), 
  (convert(datetime, '2016-11-22 02:00:22', 120)), 
  (convert(datetime, '2016-11-24 12:44:56', 120)), 
  (convert(datetime, '23/11/2016', 103)), 
  (convert(datetime, '2016-11-23 23:59:59', 120));

SELECT * from @TABELAC;  

SELECT Seq, dtHrProcesso
  from @TABELAC as C
  where Cast(dtHrProcesso as date) = '2016-11-23';
```

---

Seria ainda melhor se fizesse algo semelhante a:

```
-- código #2
declare @DataPesq date;
set @DataPesq= Convert(date, '23/11/2016', 103);

SELECT top (5) p.codinterno, c.dtHrProcesso
  from TABELA as p
       inner join TABELAC as c on c.idProcesso = p.idProcesso
  where CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) = @DataPesq;
```

Outra opção:

```
-- código #3
declare @DataPesq date;
set @DataPesq= Convert(date, '23/11/2016', 103);  -- formato dd/mm/aaaa

-- variáveis internas para delimitação de período
declare @DataInic datetime, @DataFin datetime;
set @DataInic= @DataPesq;
set @DataFin= DateAdd(ms, -3, DateAdd(day, +1, DataPesq));

--
SELECT top (5) p.codinterno, c.dtHrProcesso
  from TABELA as p
       inner join TABELAC as c on c.idProcesso = p.idProcesso
  where c.dtHrProcesso between @DataInic and @DataFin;
```

---

Quando se quer garantir que o código seja *[sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)*, deve-se evitar aplicar funções a colunas da tabela na cláusula WHERE. Entretanto, a forma

```
 Cast(coluna_datetime as date) = ...
```

é uma das exceções. Vide [Make more functions SARGable](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable).

Answer (score 0):

Sim

Verifique que

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST( '2016-11-23 05:35:33.690' AS DATE ) = '2016-11-23' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
```

retorna true e

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '2016-11-23 05:35:33.690' = '2016-11-23' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
```

retorna false

Comment: Parece que a questão agora é: o que ele quis dizer com 'problema' no retorno dos dados? Eu entendi que a pergunta dele foi basicamente essa: devo usar o cast ou não? No que eu respondi sim deve usar, já que a falta dele causa efeitos diferentes.